# JaVers Audit for @Query jpa Annotation for database query in repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-17, javers

I had repository which contains update sql query using JPA @Query annotation. Now I'm expecting that Javers need to Audit this sql query using Javers implementation. Does it is possible or not? if yes let me know how can I do this>

I am new for this implementation what I can understand javers will work only with predefined jpa methods.

but my expectation is javers work with @Query jpa annotation.

Thanks.